# Dynamic LINQ groupby and select columns from ADO datatable and return datatable

Tags: linq, dynamic

I have a ADO datatable as follows

```
tname   cname   rgname  schools mtext
tn1     cn1      rg1     1      mxt1
tn1     cn1      rg1     2      mxt1
tn1     cn1      rg1     3      mxt1
tn2     cn2      rg2     5      mxt2
tn2     cn2      rg2     8      mxt2
tn2     cn2      rg2     3      mxt2
tn3     cn1      rg1     7      mxt1
tn3     cn1      rg1     4      mxt1
```

I want to generate a table from above table by grouping and concatenating schools by comma separated. The result should look like this

```
tname   cname   rgname  schools mtext
tn1     cn1     rg1     1,2,3   mxt1
tn2     cn2     rg2     5,8,3   mxt2
tn3     cn1     rg1     7,4     mxt1
```

I know the group by columns only at runtime. I also want to have the result as a similar datatable as there are more columns(upto 15). S is it possible to use a dynamic group by and select lambda expression.

I have implemented the logic for dynamic group by, but dynamic selection is troubling me.

```
    var result = from o in DT.AsEnumerable()
         group o by new
         {
           cname = groupByCname? o.Field<string>("cname") : null,
           tname = groupByTname? o.Field<string>("tname") : null,
           rgname = groupByRGname? o.Field<string>("rgname") : null,
           mtext = groupByMtext? o.Field<string>("mtext") : null,
         } into g
       select new
        {
        //Here i want to select all columns from DT and have schools as
        // comma separated
         schools = String.Join(",",g.Select(x=>x.Field<string>  ("Schools")).ToArray())
       };
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: This comes close: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31082791/861716

Comment: In fact, your own code would do fine for me as well.

Comment: The above is expecting a single parameter, but i have possibility for multiple group by. So may be the above link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some modifications to your code.This might be not the best approach but it does gives you what you want.

```
var result = from row in
        (from t in
            (from o in dt.AsEnumerable()
             join u in dt.AsEnumerable()
             on o.Field<string>("tname") equals u.Field<string>("tname")
             select new
             {
                 o,
                 u = String.Join(",", u.Field<string>("schools"))
              })
              group t by new
              {
                  tname = t.o.Field<string>("tname"),
                  cname = t.o.Field<string>("cname"),
                  rgname = t.o.Field<string>("rgname"),
                  mtext = t.o.Field<string>("mtext")
              } into gcs
              select new
              {
                  rows = gcs.Select(x => x.o).First(),
                  schools = gcs.Select(x => x.u).Take(gcs.Key.tname.Count())
              })
    select row;

DataTable resultTable = new DataTable();
resultTable = dt.Clone();

foreach (var item in result)
{
    DataRow row = resultTable.NewRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < item.rows.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if (row.Table.Columns[i].ToString() == "schools")
        {
            row[i] = string.Join(", ", item.schools.ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            row[i] = item.rows.ItemArray[i];
        }
    }

    resultTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The group by columns are also dynamic, is my way of handling group by wrong? I mean some times group by columns will be only tname, rgname.